# Артефакты перемещения камеры в PIxel Art игре

Tags: unity3d, разработка-игр

При перемещении камеры у спрайтов возникают артефакты в виде подрагивания/переливания (или что-то вроде того). С чем это может быть связано и как поправить?

Unity 2017.3

Камера ортографическая. Все исходные текстуры имеют размер 32x32.
В настройках качества отключена анизатропная фильтрация и анти алиасинг.
В настройках спрайта:

- Pixels Per Unit - 32;
- Filter Mode - Point (no filter);
- Compression - None;
- Остальное по умолчанию.

Код перемещения персонажа:

```
transform.position += dir * moveSpeed * Time.deltaTime;
```

Код следования камеры:

```
Camera.main.transform.position = transform.position + Vector3.back * 100f;
```

, где `transform.position` - позиция объекта, за которым следует камера, а `dir` - направление движения.

Спрайты не пересекаются. Изменять исходные текстуры нельзя (т.е. размер 32x32)!

[Пример](https://webm.video/q956sV)

Comment: Вы что-то изменяли в настройках графики в юнити?

Comment: @AlexandrMaliovaniy нет, только перечисленные изменения в Quality Settings.

Comment: https://youtu.be/ryISV_nH8qw в конце видео настройка графики

Comment: @AlexandrMaliovaniy , мой проект практически идентичен тому, который на видео. Единственные настройки, которые присутствуют на видео и связаны с "графикой" - это настройки качества (Quality), а не графики (Graphics). При идентичных настройках проблема сохраняется.

Comment: анимацию перемещения камеры попробуйте сделать плавней (меньшую скорость + меньший интервал времени).

Comment: @vmchar не могли бы вы написать более подробно (особенно не понятно про интервал)? Уменьшив скорость передвижения персонажа и, как следствие, следование камеры за персонажем эффект "волн" значительно возрос.

Comment: Через Coroutine можно например попробовать двигать. Плюс посмотрите другие возможности перемения (transform.translate или vector3.lerp и т.д) такие артефакты бывают при резкком/рывковом перемещении камеры, если так, то вам нужно сгладить движение. также, на всякий случай посмотрите сколько FPS вы получаете

Comment: @vmchar через карутину передвижение станет не плавнее, а более прерывистым. Я передвигаю каждый кадр объект на довольно малые значения. При интерполяции - лерпе (плавнее уже никак) - проблема остается. FPS стабильный >60.

Comment: Есть предположение, что это связано непосредственно с пиксель артом. Возможно, с ортографическим размером или с перемещением камеры не по целым/кратным PPU значениям. Возможно, с PPU. Всё это мои догадки, на основе которых я не получил какого либо результата.

Comment: При размере экрана кратного двум и в тоже время равному кратному целому значению от размера ортографической камеры все идеально. В случае не выполнения 1 условия, но выполнения второго, появляются просветы между спрайтами. К сожалению, это все еще не ответ.

Answer (score 1):

Ко всем изложенным в вопросе действиям надо добавить еще одно на выбор:

1) Использовать Pixel Perfect камеру, что повлечет за собой изменения фактической области видимости (такой метод предлагают все, но никто не применяет - [Pixel Perfect 2D](https://blogs.unity3d.com/ru/2015/06/19/pixel-perfect-2d/));

2) Передвигать камеру только по сабпикселям:

```
step = ppu / ((Screen.Height * 0.5f) / camera.orthographicSize);
```

при таком подходе лучше делать ppu = 1, чтобы иметь возможность сдвигать камеру на относительно малые величины.

И в дополнение код, который позволяет преобразовывать координаты по "сабпиксельной сетке":

```
public Vector2 Snap(Vector2 pos)
{
    return new Vector2(pos.x - nfmod(pos.x, step), pos.y - nfmod(pos.y, step));
}

private float nfmod(float a, float b)
{
    return a - b * Mathf.Floor(a / b);
}
```